# to grep a pattern from file compare contents with another file and replace

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep

I want to grep version number in one file and replace it in another file. I want to grep 4.3.0.5 in file 1 and replace it in File 2 at 4.3.0.2. I have the below command to get the number , but how can I cut/replace it in second file??

**File1 :**
App :4.3.0.5 (or) App: 4.3.0.5-SNAPSHOT

**File2:**  **Before** editing

grid_application_distribution_url=**nexus**://com.abcd.efge.ce/App/**4.3.0.2**/tar.gz/config

**File 2** : **after** editing (**Desired Result:**)

If $VERISON in File is WITHOUT the word SNAPSHOT then in file 2

grid_application_distribution_url=**nexus**://com.abcd.efge.ce/App/**4.3.0.5**/tar.gz/config

If $VERSION has SNAPSHOT then line in file 2 should be

grid_application_distribution_url=**nexus-snapshot**://com.abcd.efge.ce/App/**4.3.0.5**/tar.gz/config

```
   VER=$(awk -F: '/^App/{sub(/ .*$/, "", $2); print $2}'/path/file1.txt)

echo $VER

if ($vER ~ /SNAPSHOT/)
/usr/bin/ssh -t -t server2.com "sub("=nexus:", ":=nexus-snapshot") /path/file2" && sub(/[^\/]+\/tar\.gz/, $VER"/tar.gz") /path/file2
```

Comment: Any time you find yourself using grep+awk or grep+sed or sed+awk you are using 1 too many tools - just use awk.

Comment: ditto, except s/awk/perl/g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This awk script can do the job (this is an enhancement of above answer from @EDMorton):

**Splitting the command in 2 as per OP's request**

```
VER=$(awk -F' *: *' '/^App/{print $2}' file1)

awk -v v="$VER" '{
     split(v, arr, "-");
     sub(/[^\/]+\/tar\.gz/, arr[1]"/tar.gz");
     if (arr[2] ~ /SNAPSHOT/)
        sub("=nexus:", ":=nexus-snapshot")
}1' file2 > tmpFile

mv tmpFile > file2
```

Comment: I need a little tweak in the same code. I have updated my original post. Can you please let me know the solution.

Comment: @sravs448: So ver file can have this content: `App: 4.3.0.5-SNAPSHOT` or `App: 4.3.0.5` right?

Comment: The above code worked in replaceing nexus or nexus-snapshot accordingly. But before the /.tar.gz, I need only the version number without the word snapshot, in either cases (If the file1 have or dont have SNAPSHOT)

Comment: The current output the above code gave me is `grid_application_distribution_url=nexus-snapshot://com.abcd.efge.ce/App/4.3.0.5-SNAPSHOT/tar.gz/config` if file1 has SNAPSHOT in it... But I am looking for `grid_application_distribution_url=nexus-snapshot://com.abcd.efge.ce/App/4.3.0.5/tar.gz/config`

Comment: I would like to go with your command provided 2days ago only, beacuse my file1 is on server1 (where I am running the script) and file 2 is on other server. Please check my original post where I have updated the code. How can I achieve the 2nd substution?

Comment: The code worked except the 1st line. So I have updated the 1st line with `VER=$(awk -F: '/^App/{sub(/ .*$/, "", $2); print $2}' file1.spec)`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is all you need:

```
awk -F': +' 'NR==FNR{v=$2;next} {sub(/[^/]+\/tar.gz/,v"/tar.gz")} 1' File1 File2 > tmp && mv tmp File2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
VERSION=($(grep -r "App:" /path/File1| awk  '{print ($2)}'))
sed -i "s/4.3.0.2/$VERSION/" File2
```

it will look for "4.3.0.2" and change by value in `$VERSION`. File2 will be updated with this change.

If you want the file to keep the same, delete the flag `-i`:

```
sed "s/4.3.0.2/$VERSION/" File2
```

You will get the result in stdout.

---

As indicated in comments, `4.3.0.2` is not like this every time. Adapted for format `X.Y.Z.W`:

```
sed "s/\/[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]\(\/tar.gz\)/\/$VERSION\1/" File2
```

Comment: It wont be 4.3.0.2 everytime...SO I want to reuse this command multiple times...I want to replace the string before "/tar.gz" to the version number

Comment: Can I use something like this?? `grep -r "App:" /path/File1| awk  '{print ($2)}' |cut -f7- -d"/"|sed 's/.\{1\}$//'`

Comment: With this you will get `:4.3.0`.

Comment: SO what should be my command to replace the entire version string?

Comment: Just updated my answer for format `X.Y.Z.W`. Anyway, I prefer @anubhava answer!

Comment: Remember to escape the periods, i.e. `\.` not just `.` which is an RE metacharacter matching any character. It's also not clear if the input numbers are always a single digit so you might want to use [0-9][0-9]* (to work on all seds).

Comment: Just updated with `[0-9][0-9]*\.` instead of `[0-9].`. Thanks, @EdMorton.